# Need help proving that a function is 1-1, onto and the equation of the inverse.

Tags: real-analysis

The problem is: Let $X = [0,\infty)$ and $Y =[0,1)$. Define $f:X\mapsto Y$ by $f(x) = \frac x{x+3}$. Show that $f$ is one-to-one, $f$ is onto and find the equation of the inverse $f^{-1}:Y\mapsto X$.

I understand the basic definitions of why a function is onto and $1-1$, but not sure how to go about a proof and work around the ranges of $X$ and $Y$.

I know a function is $1-1$ if for all $a,b\in A, f(a) = f(b)$ implies that $a = b$.  I know a function is onto where $f:A\mapsto B$ if $B = \text{rng}(f)$

Comment: Beginning with the function identified as $f(x)=\frac x{x+3}$, can you show that it is onto?  What are you able to demonstrate so far?

Comment: I really cant do anything. Ive been re-reading definitions and searching for example problems for hours but i really just dont understand what to do.

Answer (score 3):

From your own definitions:

- Suppose $\frac{a}{a+3} = \frac{b}{b+3}$ for some given $a, b \in [0, \infty)$. Can you manipulate this equation to show that $a=b$ must hold?
- To find the inverse of $f$, manipulate the equation $y = \frac{x}{x+3}$ so that $x$ is equal to some expression involving $y$.
- If $y \in [0, 1)$ is given, can you find some $x$ such that $f(x) = y$? (Using the $f^{-1}$ may help.) If so, then $f$ is onto.

Comment: I dont understand how you are supposed to prove that a must equal b.. it seems intuitive to me that it must be true. As for the inverse problem, how are you supposed to get X by itself? Every way I try ends in having to cancel X's out.

Comment: If you cross multiply you get $a(b+3) = b(a+3)$ which is equivalent to $ab(1) + a(3) = ab(1) + b(3)$. Can you see now why they must be equal?

Comment: That makes alot of sense. Thank you. To find the equation of the inverse do you simply have to get x by itself?